# OpenVPN stuck in Connecting

Tags: openvpn

I recently installed openVPN3 on a Oracle Linux Server for an auto-login profile. I imported the profiles successfully to the server, however, it is stucked on Session path.

```
[root@jump openvpn3]# openvpn3 session-start --config /etc/openvpn3/config.conf
Using configuration profile from file: /etc/openvpn3/config.conf
Session path: /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/39fe0ebes23d2s4f8as8487sadce1a055a73
```

I've tried monitoring it on verbose level 6, but the info I got is not helpful

```
[root@jump openvpn3]# openvpn3 log --log-level 6 --config config.conf
Waiting for session to start ... Done
Attaching to session /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/9779d843sb63es46fesa0b2sd1e848586d05
2023-03-16 16:10:35 [STATUS] Connection, Configuration OK: config_path=/net/openvpn/v3/configuration/1b4e2fe5x2e5dx4e5cx94bex39f0c1b19d89
2023-03-16 16:10:35 Client INFO: Starting connection
2023-03-16 16:10:35 [STATUS] Connection, Client connecting
```

Is there any other checking I should do for this?

```
[root@jump openvpn3]# openvpn3 configs-list
Configuration path
Imported                        Last used                 Used
Name                                                      Owner
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/net/openvpn/v3/configuration/1b4e2fe5x2e5dx4e5cx94bex39f0c1b19d89
Thu Mar 16 15:24:28 2023        Thu Mar 16 16:27:57 2023  8
config.conf                                     root
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this this morning with a connection that had been working for 13 months uninterrupted. For me I was using the Kansas City MO region, and I made a new profile config and chose Oregon instead and it started working, so perhaps it was an issue with the servers in that region.